# How many different telephone numbers are there if it is assumed that each number contains not more than seven digits?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many different telephone numbers are there if it is assumed that each number contains not more than seven digits (a telephone number may begin with a zero)?

I am a learning mathematics as a hobby. Please excuse if the question is very rookie.

Comment: can numbers repeat??

Comment: Please edit your question to include your own attempt at solving the problem and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: Sure.Numbers can repeat. Now if numbers can repeat I came up with the answer 10^7 however the textbook answer seems to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see "not more than" or other similar key phrases (e.g. at least), you should break it up into cases.

Case 1: There are exactly 7 numbers. You've already calculated in your comments to be $10^7$.

Case 2: There are exactly 6 numbers.

And continue until you've exhausted all possibilities of "no more than 7 numbers."

Comment: If I understand correctly then the solution is - 10^7+10^6+10^5+...+10?

Comment: Yes that looks fine.

Comment: The textbook however tells the solution as 10(10^7-1)/9. Did we miss something?

Comment: Did you copy the question exactly as it was presented?

Comment: yes ,I just rechecked it.

Comment: The two answers are equivalent.  The $n$th partial sum $$s_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} ar^{n - 1} = a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots + ar^{n - 1} = a(1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^{n - 1})$$ of a geometric series with initial term $a$ and common ratio $r$ is $$s_n = a \frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r}$$ as you can check by multiplying $1 - r$ by $1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^{n - 1}$.  Substituting $a = 10$, $r = 10$, and $n = 7$ yields $$s_7 = 10 \frac{1 - 10^7}{1 - 10} = 10 \frac{10^7 - 1}{10 - 1} = 10 \frac{10^7 - 1}{9}$$